# Error: unexpected inconsistency; run fsck manually

Tags: boot, filesystem

When I start my PC, the following commands appear in cmd space:

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on `/dev/sda1` requires a manual `fsck`

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in-commands.

(initramfs)_
```

Can anybody help in sorting out the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

1. At the command-line, enter: "fsck  /dev/sda6"
2. Enter `y` when prompted to perform fixes.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789454

Comment: tks this solution works like charm in my Mint 18.3.

Comment: With an encrytped partition (the standard Ubuntu encryption choice at install) it's: `fsck /dev/mapper/sda6_crypt`. Luckily tab-autocompletion works.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid data loss due to disk failure, this command should be given from a live Ubuntu session.
Follow these steps:

- You should burn a live Ubuntu CD.
- Insert the live CD and **try Ubuntu without installing.**
- Open a terminal and type the following command:

  ```
  sudo fsck /dev/sda1
  ```
- When prompted, type `y` to fix the errors.

That should be all. Your system will boot normally once this fix has been applied.

Comment: I starred at that message and the `(initframfs)` prompt is a number of times and thought the same as you. Luckily, it _is_ a prompt, allowing `echo hi`, `ls` and most importantly `fsck /dev/…`, so luckily no need to go through a live cd.